# In $U(55)$ show $x \mapsto x^3$ is injective

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am stuck on showing that $\varphi : U(55) \to U(55) $ given by $x \mapsto x^3$ is an isomorphism.

I already knwo that $\psi: U(n)\to U(n), \psi(x) = x^k$ is an isomorphism if and only if $\gcd(k,n) = 1$. But I wanted to do a proof without using this knowledge just to practice.

Now I have this:

If $x^3 = y^3$ then $0 = x^3 - y^3 = (x-y)(x^2 + xy + y^2)$. If I could show that $x^2 + xy + y^2$ can't be zero then I'd be done but I don't see how to do it.

> How to show that $x^2 + xy + y^2$ can't be zero in $U(55)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$\eqalign{x^2+xy+y^2\equiv0\quad
  &\Rightarrow\quad 4x^2+4xy+4y^2\equiv0\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad (2x+y)^2+3y^2\equiv0\cr}$$
modulo $55$, which implies $(2x+y)^2+3y^2\equiv0\pmod5$.  Since a square modulo $5$ can only be $0,1$ or $4$ it is easy to rule out all possibilities except $x,y\equiv0\pmod5$.  But this is impossible since $x,y$ are units modulo $55$.

Alternative: same thing modulo $11$.  It's a bit more work but essentially the same argument.